# how to solve image upload buttons missing in magento (in google chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, magento-1.9

```
 **`I am new for magento.`**
```

Browse files and upload files buttons missing in magento (in google chrome)?

When adding new product information then can't seeing this two buttons.

```
Magento version 1.9

Now I tried for this solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Chrome settings.
2. Scroll down to Advanced settings
3. Under Privacy click Content settings
4. Scroll down for Flash
5. Click Exceptions and add your Magento store url to the exceptions list. If running your store over https, be sure to include https in the url (https://myshop.com)
6. Save settings and refresh your store admin page and see if your Upload and Browse buttons are back and running (they should be).